# PHP and MySQLi check to see if the table exists and if it doesn't create it

Tags: php, mysqli

Attempting to use this to check to see if the table exists and if it doesn't create it

```
if ( !f_tableExists($table, DB_NAME) ) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID),
        timestamp int NOT NULL,
        ip int NOT NULL
    )";

    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

}
```

where f_tableExists does the following to check if it exists.

```
function f_tableExists($tablename, $database = false) {

if(!$database) {
    $res = mysqli_query("SELECT DATABASE()");
    $database = mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);
}

$res = mysqli_query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = '$database'
    AND table_name = '$tablename'   
");

return mysqli_data_seek($res, 0) == 1;
}
```

Getting the result 'Invalid query:'

No table is being made and hence I assume some of my mysqli query code (CREATE TABLE....ip int NOT NULL) or (SELECT COUNT...= '$tablename') or another bit is wrong and/or not working? I don't know which bit or why?

Answer (score 4):

Just use query with `IF NOT EXISTS` without checking

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID),
        timestamp int NOT NULL,
        ip int NOT NULL
    )";
```

Also, need pass connection into [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

P.S. relative joke: http://www.bash.org/?725783

Comment: Still getting the same result with that, so maybe  $result = mysqli_query($sql); is not working?

Comment: @Quickcoins , please check mysqli_query signature.

Comment: how do i check mysqli_query signature, never heard of that before?

Comment: Okay so i have done $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); and I am still getting the same result, does that cover the parameters? Still getting the same problem

Comment: @Quickcoins, you need pass link into `mysqli_error`

Comment: so die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($link)); That still doesn't work and no error message

Comment: @Quickcoins, please update your code in your question. Also give us full error output

Answer (score 0):

hey this how you could have done it:

**create  a mysqli php connection:**

```
<?php
$__DATABASE__='centralfeed_feed';
$__USER__='root';
$__PASSWORD__='';
$__HOST__='localhost';

$con=mysqli_connect($__HOST__,$__USER__,$__PASSWORD__,$__DATABASE__);

?>
```

**then make the mysqli request to database:**

```
<?php

     if(mysqli_query($con,"DESCRIBE  users ")){
        echo "exists";
    }else{
        echo "dont exists";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit;
 ?>
```

**then your done !!**

Always remember to close connection when ever your done using them or note using  them connections not just in php mysqli but all the time(in other languages as well).